# rails activerecord transaction blocks don't seem to not commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, transactions

I've a rails app that I'm crashing on purpose..  it's local and I'm just hitting ctrl + c and killing it mid way through processing records..

To my mind the records in the block shouldn't have been committed.. Is this a postgres "error" or a rails "error", or a dave ERROR?

```
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        UploadStage.where("id in (#{ids.join(',')})").update_all(:status => 2);

        records.each do |record|
          record.success = process_line(record.id, klas, record.hash_value).to_s[0..250]
          record.status = 1000
          record.save();
        end    
      end
```

I generate my ids by reading out all the records where the status is 1.
Nothing but this function sets the status to 1000..

If the action crashes for what ever reason, I'd expect there to be no records in the database with status = 2... 
This is not what I'm seeing though.  Half the records have status 1000, the other half have status 2.. .

Am I missing something?
How can I make sure there are no 2's if the app crashes?

---

EDIT:
I found this link  http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/beware-of-threadkill-or-your-activerecord-transactions-are-in-danger-of-being-partially-committed/

Comment: Consider enabling detailed query logging and see what Rails is doing. Use `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` then examine the PostgreSQL logs. It's impossible to say if this is a PostgreSQL issue when all you show is Rails code, but I'd be amazed; ActiveRecord is a bizarre and quirky beast, while PostgreSQL's transaction code is exceedingly mature and well tested. Personally I won't be surprised if ActiveRecord is "helpfully" committing your transaction when it gets the signal to terminate.

Comment: What happens if you `kill -9` (i.e. SIGKILL) instead? A Ctrl+C is a fairly gentle way to shut things down and Rails might interpret it as "stop accepting new connections shut things down once everything I'm currently doing has finished".

Comment: sure... what happens if I walk past the server and trip on the power cord.. I'm trying to simulate an ungraceful crash... the ctrl + c is as close as I think I need to test right now... as it's failing, I figured I'd fix it first.

Comment: @CraigRinger .. any thoughts on how to get it to not "helpfully"?

Comment: It is of course possible that half of your records are invalid and not being saved. Use save! instead if this could be happening. Also, @muistooshort raises a valid point - if the transaction saves nothing under that circumstance, then its behaviour is correct.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks.. I eventually tracked it down to an activerecord bug.  Ctrl-c does indeed allow for a gracefull shutdown, and the ensure block of the transaction code does a commit if a kill is received.  It's not what I'd expect, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Comment: @daveatflow Yet more evidence that friends don't let friends use ActiveRecord :S . There's a workaround described on the link you found. The right answer would be to fix ActiveRecord so it doesn't commit when you kill a thread (!).

Comment: @Craig: I like Ruby a lot but the more I use Rails the more it seems like a big pile of kludges with good marketing.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah ... I've been using Java EE - EJB3.1, JTA, JAX-RS,  CDI, etc - and it's buggy, frustrating, over-engineered, bloated and horrible, yet the more I see about Rails here the happier I am that I went for Java EE instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger I rallied against rails, but eventually I got the feeling my job was on the line.  Anyone taking a look at the array implementation alone would question it as a viable tool.  I went so far as to create a new SO account because I don't want my real username associated to it :)

Comment: Here's the link the Archive as the original post is not available anymore: https://web.archive.org/web/20141224073845/https://coderrr.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/beware-of-threadkill-or-your-activerecord-transactions-are-in-danger-of-being-partially-committed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected and as confirmed by dave's update, it looks like ActiveRecord will commit a half-finished transaction under some circumstances when you kill a thread. Woo, safe! See [dave's link](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/beware-of-threadkill-or-your-activerecord-transactions-are-in-danger-of-being-partially-committed/) for detailed explanation and mitigation options.

If you're simulating hard crash (host OS crash or plug-pull), control-C is absolutely not the right approach. Use `Control-\` to send a `SIGQUIT`, which is generally not handled, or use `kill -KILL` to hard-kill the process with no opportunity to do cleanup. `Control-C` sends `SIGINT` which is a gentle signal that's usually attached to a clean shutdown handler.

In general, if you're debugging issues like this, you should enable detailed query logging and see what Rails is doing. Use `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` then examine the PostgreSQL logs.